# WPF ListView, binding a SortedList containing <string,string>

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

(Newbie alert!) (Edited to add code after I figured out the editor!)

I'm not sure I am on the right track here. I have a generic SortedList with two string parameters. I'd like to bind the list to a ListView with two columns, one showing the Key and one the Value.

I have seen an example with a  pair, where the object is a class with named properties. However I don't really think I need to go so far as to build another class (do I?) because all I have is a simple set of pairs of strings.

Here's my XAML:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,51,0,68" Name="fieldsList" Width="225" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridViewColumn Header="Field Name" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Field Value" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Code:

```
 private SortedList<string, string> myFields = new SortedList<string, string>();

// fieldsList.SetBinding( ??, ??);
```

So my question really, I guess is how to link the myFields Items to the ListView?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please always post what you have tried so far (code) in your question.

Comment: Thanks! I added some code...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create other class, every item of a SortedList have two properties Key and Value. So, you can use both properties in your ListView:

### The view

```
<Window
    x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### The ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public SortedList<string,string> Items { get; set; } = new SortedList<string, string>();

    public ViewModel()
    {
        //Add data to Items, for example
    }
}
```

If you want two columns you can custom the item template with a grid with tho columns and that's all.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: @ganchito55 This is a problem with all new people in SO community.

Comment: Can you show the code behind? Do you use the SetBinding method to set up the link?

Comment: I don't use code behind, I use the MVVM architecture ( `ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"`), with this code the link is created, you can also use `ListView.ItemsSource` to assign the items source.

Comment: I am sorry for slowness, but I cannot see how the ListView knows _which_ SortedList (in my case, myFields) to use. I have several. I tried to browse for this in the Bindings part of the IDE but could not find it.

Comment: The ListView look for the Items property of the ViewModel class, because it's its DataContext. I have just added more code to show it.